# Installing Server 20.04 on MBR

Tags: mbr

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 onto a preformatted MBR disk with these OS's on these partitions:

1. Fat32 (bootable with msdos.98S)
2. NTFS (Windows 10 / Windows server 2019)
3. Fat32 (Flagged as bootable for mounting /boot)
4. EXT4 (For Ubuntu Mount / 20.04)

Before you ask I have a working drive in GPT without Dos that set up beautifully. I have been asked to get a drive with Dos working for a very specific reason that I am unable to divulge.

I have tried the above, as well as trying to set the drive up as a hybrid MBR but so far have been unable to even load windows on the NTFS partition.

If you have questions please feel free to ask and I will answer the best of my ability. I know this is a stretch as MBR is a dinosaur, but I do have a legitimate need.

Thanks for any help.
James

Comment: where do you get stuck? does the install medium boot?

Comment: It get stuck at mounting /boot. It will not go any further. File system mounts just fine.

Comment: hmm so let me get it straight ... you boot the install medium and then you use the "try ubuntu" option or "install ubuntu"?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the first Fat32 partition has already been made bootable with the base Dos files. I install Windows 10 without issue, and Ubuntu goes fine right up to selecting the mount /boot. I'm wondering what I am missing. Used to use Server 16.04 and install the Linux portion on an unformatted portion of the drives that went perfectly.

Comment: With it being the server version I go straight to install.

Comment: "install the Linux portion on an unformatted portion of the drives that went perfectly." - so why not delete the to patiotions allocated for ubuntu and do it the same way?

Comment: so if I follow you correctly you would be at step 8 in this tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#8-configure-storage

Comment: Actually step 5 of this tutorial https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-20-04-lts-server-installation-guide/

Comment: It will not allow me to install to the unformatted portion of the HDD.

Comment: okay but step 5 is quite big , so perhaps you could provide a picture or be more clear about where exactly it dies... you have set sda  as boot device then; did you create a new gpt partition? I believe not .. you try to set sda3 as /boot adn here it hangs?

Comment: Set custom storage layout, then choose sda4 as file system /, choose sda3 as /boot. It is at this point that it tells me to I need to select a boot disk.

Comment: okay thx, one more question so did you skip the step in the image after the tutorial says "So, let’s start creating the partitions,  ..." ? - where the (2) is printed next to "use as boot device?"

Comment: Unfortunately that option is not available using the preformatted partition that I need for dos and MBR overall.

Comment: What do you mean /boot? It only looks like you have a Windows boot partition which you cannot use for Linux. You probably do not want nor need a /boot partition for Ubuntu unless using LVM with encryption. Grub will only boot one Windows unless you move boot flag so each install has Windows boot files, but then Windows will only boot the one with the boot flag. Grub does not use boot flag and only looks for Windows boot files, so will boot every install with the boot files. Windows normally overwrites boot files in boot flag partition and adds other installs to BCD (if Windows7, 8 or 10)

Comment: okay, so this might really be due to MBR, if your system is connected to the internet the installer asked if you want to update it - did you do that? if so I guess the only way might be to use an 18.04.4 or 16.04.6 install medium, make a clean install and then update and upgrade ; sorry -- or is this out of option due to other special needs?

Comment: I'm assuming no update available as it does not prompt for one. when trying to run the update it fails. Not sure why. However we have a lot of hardware rolling through the area that needs clean installs before deployment and that is why a clean install is preferable.

Comment: okay I  am sorry, but i can't help you ... perhaps if you edit your question to include the info we collected and perhaps provide some images of the error message where you get stuck, someone might come along and help you --- anyways if you have a minmal install that you upgraded and then put on all your server stuff still apears to me the easiest way -- even big companies upgrade working systems from 16.04/18.04 to 20.04 - and to me it appears this is due to necessity of MBR the only way ---  or go to canonical and ask them - as it seems you are some kind of company -- sorry

Comment: No worries. thanks for giving it a try. And Yes we are a bigger company. With the need for protecting proprietary info, sorry I wan't able to give you screen shots and such. I'll try compiling what we have and submitting a new question tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can mount ubuntu system on **/**, so you should try mounting ubuntu system on **/** instead **/boot** and partition should be ext4.
you can see what I selected in mount and format options [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ss1.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1216883)

Comment: well I don’t know what you mean to say. I never said thank you. If you mean to convey something else please message again

Comment: @NonnyMoose please be very careful during review, especially when you leave a comment. This is certainly not a thank you answer.
Sorry Jym. However, David is correct - can you [edit] this post to include the essential detail from that link in this post?